# Book about kids who leave their isolated dome on another planet

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I am trying to find the name of a book I read in 2007/2008, when I was in grade 5. It was about a family of four, two adults and two children, that lived in a dome and were isolated from the outside world. I think everyone in the society lived like this, in isolated domes.

It took place on another planet and they were forbidden to leave their dome, and/or they were told they would die if they left. The atmosphere outside the dome was very windy and dusty. The lives of the family members were strictly controlled, they had to complete certain chores at certain times and all of their food was rationed. At one point the kids (a girl and a boy) decided to leave the dome for some reason. I think they wore space suits.

This is where things get more fuzzy. What I remember is that they almost died walking to some other, larger dome they saw in the distance. They passed out before they made it and woke up inside the larger dome, which had a garden and there were a bunch of other kids. I also remember there was an older person who was the "leader" of this larger dome. The cover of the book was yellow.

Side note, I saw some similar questions where the answer was *The Lotus Caves* by John Christopher. I don't think this is the one I am looking for.

Comment: 'The Lotus Caves' was a favourite book of mine as a kid. I can confirm it is nothing like your description.  Completely different, except for the part about 2 kids  leaving a dome.

Comment: From the title alone, I would have indeed guessed it was *The Lotus Caves*—but evidently not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[The Other Place](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/h/monica-hughes/other-place.htm)" by Monica Hughes?

[image: The Other Place]

> The Fairweather family, mom, dad, eight-year-old Billy and pre-teen Alison, have just been charged with crimes of subversion against the all-powerful World Government. Now they are about to become "disappeareds", all traces of their existence wiped cleanly away. The Fairweathers are sentenced to five years in the mysterious penal colony of Habitat W- a self-contained, controlled and eerily sterile indoor place that opens to a seething desert of fierce wind and sand. Strangely, Mr. and Mrs. Fairweather robotically resign themselves to their fate. But Billy is convinced that somewhere beyond the barren desert, there is a paradise to be found. His escape from Habitat W sets off a chain of startling events that helps Alison to discover "the other place" and a new hope for their future.

[There is more information about the book on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_Place_(novel)).